# How can I call uiautomator-api directly without using 'am instrument'?

Tags: android-uiautomator

I am a beginner in using uiautomator.

I know that we can run uiautomator-test-case by 'adb shell am instrument ~' command.

At this time, I am trying to call uiautomator-api directly.

Here is my sample class file.

```
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiSelector;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;

public class ExecutorBase extends UiAutomatorTestCase {

    public void pressHomeWrapper() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
        Log.d(TAG, "getUiDevice: " + getUiDevice());
        getUiDevice().pressHome();      
    }
    public TagResult pressHomeUA() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
        boolean isPass = false;     
        this.pressHomeWrapper();        
        return TagResult.NEW(isPass);
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to call pressHomeUA(), I get a RuntimeException error below.

```
08-20 17:53:30.687: E/JavaBinder(14377): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
08-20 17:53:30.687: E/JavaBinder(14377): java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
08-20 17:53:30.687: E/JavaBinder(14377):    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase.<init>(UiAutomatorTestCase.java:5)
08-20 17:53:30.687: E/JavaBinder(14377):    at com.lge.art.play.script.tag.ExecutorBase.<init>(ExecutorBase.java:247)
08-20 17:53:30.687: E/JavaBinder(14377):    at com.lge.art.play.script.runner.ScriptRunner.<init>(ScriptRunner.java:101)
```

So I want to know how I can call uiautomator-api directly.

Could you let me know that it is possible?

Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: Are you running on the device?

Comment: But the class extends to `UiAutomatorTestCase`, can you run by `am instrument ..` ?

Comment: Yes, I am running it on device. I really want to know how to use a uiautomator api directly in any android project?